# If statement with {} and without {} inside a For loop

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I have a loop of queues in a vector and I need to search in the loop of queues to find the minimum index queue as well as the maximum size queue.

I'm using the following code

```
int min_index = 0;
int max_size = -1;
std::size_t size = q.size();
for( i=0; i<size; i++){ //accessing loop of queues
    if(q[min_index].size() > q[i].size())
        min_index = i; // Now q[min_index] is min_index is the minimum size queue
    if(q[i].size() > max_size)
        max_size = q[i].size(); // maximum size queue
}
```

I have a small doubt whether to use the `{}` for each `if statement` like the below code

```
int min_index = 0;
    int max_size = -1;
    std::size_t size = q.size();
    for( i=0; i<size; i++){ //accessing loop of queues
        if(q[min_index].size() > q[i].size()){
            min_index = i; // Now q[min_index] is the shortest queue
              }
        if(q[i].size() > max_size){
            max_size = q[i].size(); // longest queue        
            } 
}
```

Which one is correct and what will be exactly difference with and without `{}`. Sorry if it is a silly question. I am new to programming.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "if loop". If there's only one statement in a block, `{}` is optional, it's a matter of style.

Comment: i am sorry i changed it is 'if statement'

Comment: [Should curly braces appear on their own line?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2715/should-curly-braces-appear-on-their-own-line)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, there is **no difference** between the two codes.

```
if(SOMETHING)
   DO_SOMETHING;
```

is the **same** as

```
if(SOMETHING) {
   DO_SOMETHING;
}
```

But

```
 if(SOMETHING)
   DO_SOMETHING_1;
   DO_SOMETHING_2;   //DO_SOMETHING_2 will be performed whether the `if` condition
                     //is satisfied or not
```

is **not** the same as

```
 if(SOMETHING) {
   DO_SOMETHING_1;
   DO_SOMETHING_2;   //DO_SOMETHING_2 will be performed only if the `if` condition
 }                   //is satisfied, since it is inside the curly parentheses
```

In your case, since the `if` block contains only one statement, there is no need for curly parentheses (**although, if it confuses you, it's recommended to use them for clarifying things**)..

Answer (score 3):

Usually, the best rule to apply is:

> If any doubt, use the {}

Same goes for `()`

Yet in your case, both are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

They will run the same but it is some people prefer to use the {} that way if you need to go back and have more than one line of code after your if statement you don't have to add {}.

Comment: Leaving out the {} initially doesn't mean you can't add them later.

Comment: I know that, I just hate going back and adding them and then adding the new line of code... personally I can tell when I'm gonna need more than 1 line after an if statement but if you can't then I would suggest that he just add them so that he doesn't have to go back and add them later. This question is purely preference based though.

Answer (score 0):

The brackets when used that way is called a block-statement, and is used to encapsulate one or more statements. One such block is equal to one statement, which satisfies the parser that expects one statements as the body of an `if` statement.

So no, there is really no difference between the two. In one you have a single statement, in the other another kind of single statement, that just happens to contain other statements.

Answer (score 0):

***No difference:***

```
int min_index = 0;
int max_size = -1;
std::size_t size = q.size();
for( i=0; i<size; i++){ //accessing loop of queues
    if(q[min_index].size() > q[i].size())
        min_index = i; // Now q[min_index] is min_index is the minimum size queue
    if(q[i].size() > max_size)
        max_size = q[i].size(); // maximum size queue
}
```

The only difference will be if you want to write more then one line in the if, for example

```
if(q[min_index].size() > q[i].size())
        min_index = i;
        ++i;
```

In this case only `min_index = i;` line will be called if your `if(q[min_index].size() > q[i].size())` is true.